# How to remove lines with a pattern if the next line matches the same pattern?

Tags: python, regex, pandas, text, text-mining

I have a dataframe with a column containing logs for a ticket per row. Here is an example of the log:

```
99645,
\Submitted',
 '\Modifications made 2015/01/01',
 'x_change0:   -->  info0',
 'y_status1:   -->  info1',
 'z_change2:   -->  info2',
 'y_change3:   -->  info3',
 '\Modifications made 2015/01/03',
 '\Modifications made 2015/01/05',
 '\Modifications made 2015/01/07',
 'w_change0:   -->  info0',
 'a_status1:   -->  info1',
 '\Modifications made 2015/01/07',
.
.
.
```

I want to delete all lines, which are not followed by changes. The following regex matches the content I am looking for [RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/i53Qzw/2):

```
pattern = '(?sm)Modifications\s*((?!Modifications\s*).)*'
re.findall(pattern, dataframe['log'])
```

Expected result per cell in dataframe['log']:

```
Modifications made 2015/01/01',
'change0:   -->  info0',
'change1:   -->  info1',
'change2:   -->  info2',
'change3:   -->  info3',
'Modifications made 2015/01/07',
'change0:   -->  info0',
'change1:   -->  info1',
'
```

How do I delete the unwanted lines in the cells? Or how can I replace the string inside the cells with the filtered string?

Comment: Does `'\Modifications made 2015/01/07'`, needs to be removed?

Comment: Are those backslashes `'\M` actually present in `df['log']` values?

Comment: How about this [`(?sm)Modifications[^,]+,(?:(?!^\s*'\\Modifications).)*\b`](https://regex101.com/r/EvU55a/1/)

Comment: @DanielMesejo the last one, yes, since there was a modification on that day, but no relevant changes.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Yes, they are. However they are probably the result of my previous text preprocessing.

Comment: could you put a sample of how the dataframe structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with @Code Maniac's RegEx solution: 
`(?sm)Modifications[^,]+,(?:(?!^\s*'\\Modifications).)*\b`.

Replace cell string with the following loop:

```
pattern = r"(?sm)Modifications[^,]+,(?:(?!^\s*'\\Modifications).)*\b"
pattern = re.compile(pattern=pattern)
df['tickethist'] = ""

for i in range(len(df['log'])):
    search = []
    log = df.at[i, 'log']
    for match in pattern.findall(str(log)):
        search.append(match)
    df.at[i, 'tickethist'] = search
```

Answer (score 0):

Complex filtering using [`pd.Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html) and `str.startswith` functions.

Initial dataframe:

```
In [87]: df                                                                                                    
Out[87]: 
                                  log
0   '\Modifications made 2015/01/01',
1            'change0:   -->  info0',
2            'change1:   -->  info1',
3            'change2:   -->  info2',
4            'change3:   -->  info3',
5   '\Modifications made 2015/01/03',
6   '\Modifications made 2015/01/05',
7   '\Modifications made 2015/01/07',
8            'change0:   -->  info0',
9            'change1:   -->  info1',
10  '\Modifications made 2015/01/07',
```

Dropping rows on condition (add `inplace=True` papam to modify *in-place*):

```
In [88]: df.drop(df[(df.log.str.startswith("'\Modifications")) & ((df.log.shift(-1).str.startswith("'\Modificat
    ...: ions")) | (~df.log.shift(-1).str.startswith("'change", na=False)) | df.log.shift(-1).isna())].index)  
Out[88]: 
                                 log
0  '\Modifications made 2015/01/01',
1           'change0:   -->  info0',
2           'change1:   -->  info1',
3           'change2:   -->  info2',
4           'change3:   -->  info3',
7  '\Modifications made 2015/01/07',
8           'change0:   -->  info0',
9           'change1:   -->  info1',
```

Comment: Hello Roman, thank you for your answer. It is very complex. However there are a few things I probably should mention. Each log is contained in a single cell. Moreover there is no recurrent "change" string, it was just my way of censoring the data. I will update my question.

Comment: @Audiogott, *Each log is contained in a single cell.* - that's doubtful, and makes the task even more vague then it seemed on the 1st glance. Looks like that's just another case when my effort is wasted

Comment: What do you mean by doubtful? This is how my dataframe is structured: ```data = {'ID': [99645], 'log': ["'99645, \Submitted', '\Modifications made 2015/01/01'"], 'attribute1': ['somestring'], 'attribute2': ['somestringaswell'] }```. The log column is a result of appending ID related logs to the column. Forgive me if I am not being clear enough, since I am rather new to this.